# Is there a use case where RDBMS is the best data store for querying only?

Tags: database-design, nosql, rdbms

I am trying to figure out whether there is any legitimate use case for Relational Data Store (like MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc) in DDD, Event sourcing and its projections. Hear me out.

In event sourcing your OLTP and write side is solved for you. For OLAP and the whole read/query side, you are free to create a projection - store data from the source of truth in a way that will fit your query use case the best way possible. So that the read is extremely fast. Therefore I am trying to figure out, if I am only to query the data store, is there a use case, that I would want to store in RDBMS/Relational Data Store? I see that for any use case there is a better Data Store than Relational.

- Do you need to get one item by ID? - key-value Data store is the best
- Do you need some nested structures to query? - Document Data store is the best
- Do you want to query relations between structures? - Graph Data store is the best
- Do you want to do some analytical processing? Aggregations, averages and what not? - Column Data store is the best.

Is my thinking correct? Do you see any flaws? Read use cases that RDBMS solves the best?

Comment: Many of your stated technologies are slowly being incorporated into one or more RDBMS.  Any answer given could be outdated in a few years.  It would be best to do a Proof-of-Concept and judge from that.  If you need to store *valid data*, RDBMS is probably your only choice.

Comment: First, I am not really sure what do you mean by `valid data`. My source of truth lies elsewhere. I Use it to create highly optimized transformations for querying only. These updates happen in the background process. I am asking whether there is a one query question that would be best answered by RDBMS. And I can't imagine any. Even is other types of data stores are incorporated into some RDBMSs, It would still be reasonable to argue that specialized data store would be more performant than a hybrid one.

Comment: Relational databases are really good at looking up things by primary key. They are also really good at doing aggregation "and what not" (many relational DBMS offer column store extension or storage options) and they become increasingly efficient when handling unstructured data (JSON). Are the use cases where a specialized solution is much better then others? Most definitely. Do the traditional relational databases cover a really wide range of uses cases with perfectly acceptable performance. Definitely yes as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is exactly my point. Do you want one DB that will do pretty much everything pretty well? Use RDBMS. But if you can pick a Datastore type for each use case that will fit the best, would you ever use RDMBS? Nowadays it is pretty easy to spin up 4 docker containers with for example REDIS, NEO4J, ELASTICSEARCH and DRUID. And just pick the best option for each use case. I am looking for a case where I would say - for this PosgreSQL is the best option. And I cannot think of any. That is pretty much my question.

Comment: "*it is pretty easy to spin up 4 docker containers with for example REDIS, NEO4J, ELASTICSEARCH and DRUID*" and increase your maintenance and configuration work by 10. The more moving part your system has, the more complicated it gets. How are you synchronizing the data between all those systems?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah, no, not really I have Redis or Memcached for pretty much every project for the cache. I have ElasticSearch for pretty much every project for faceted navigation and language search. Druid I would need only in very complicated analytical processing and reports. So it is really only e question of Neo4j vs RDBMS. And I would argue that Graph DB is better for relation traversal than relational. But this is really outside of the scope of the question. Maybe I do not care. Maybe I am willing to trade the infrastructure complexity for better read performance.

Comment: alleged better read performance.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yeah, but isn't that the point of all those different types of databases? Specialization in answering one concrete type of question and optimization for it? Sure, it depends very much on configuration, as everything does, but all other things being equal, why would a database specialized in answering one type of question (like graph database for traversing relationships) be slower than a generalist database for the same question? (like MySQL that would have to join every relationship)

Comment: Discussion in **[chat room for this question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106840/discussion-between-patrick-kusebauch-and-mustaccio)**

Answer (score 1):

I find your question a bit confusing, as you mix different concept domains togeter.

RDBMS stands for "**Relational** database management system". If your data model is relational in nature, you use an RDBMS to store, process and query it. How it optimizes these things physically is an implementation detail (your "Column Data store" is one example).

If your data model is strictly non-relational, you might choose a different DBMS, such as key-value store type, whose implementation is more optimized for the corresponding use cases.

Comment: I know. If it makes it any clearer, a restatement of the question would be something like - Is there a case where read-only data is relational in nature and a graph data store would not be a better option? Since I would argue that if I want to query relations, the Graph data store is optimized for that. If I do not want to query relations than I do not need Relational data store either.

Comment: I think RDBMS are great for writes and transactions and OLTP in general. And for a small project where you do OLTP and OLAP (read and write) over the same data store. But if you separate it and read from different DB then you write to, is there a read use case for Relational DB that is not better served by some other data store type?

Comment: You misunderstand what "relational" means.

Comment: If you think so, would you care to elaborate? How the `relational` aspect of RDBMS cannot be expressed and queried in a Graph DB? That I argue is despite the name better suited for that use case?

Comment: You can start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model. Hint: "relation" and "relationship" have no relation.

Comment: yeah, this is not very helpful. What do I misunderstand about them in your opinion? Can you give a concrete example for only querying data where A RDBMS is the best possible type of data store?

Comment: RDBMS _is not a data store_, which is what I've been trying to say. Or, to be more precise, it's much more than a data store (or stores) it might use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106840/discussion-between-patrick-kusebauch-and-mustaccio).